# CLIPS: OR conditional element that evaluates to TRUE if and only if 2 or more of its internal patterns are TRUE

Tags: clips

A normal (or) element evaluates to TRUE if 1 or more of the patterns are matched:

```
(or
    (object (name name-1))
    (object (name name-2))
    (object (name name-3))
    (object (name name-4))
)
```

*The question is*: is there a simple way to create a modified (or) element that evaluates to TRUE if **2** or more of the patterns are matched?

The dumb brute way of doing this would of course be the following, but I'm convinced there's a smoother way.

```
(or
    (and
        (object (name name-1))
        (object (name name-2))
    )
    (and
        (object (name name-1))
        (object (name name-3))
    )
    (and
        (object (name name-1))
        (object (name name-4))
    )
    (and
        (object (name name-2))
        (object (name name-3))
    )

    ...

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to match more than two objects, then use that same number of patterns and discard extraneous permutations with a call to a utility function:

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> (defclass X (is-a USER))
CLIPS>  
(definstances Xs
   (name-0 of X)
   (name-1 of X)
   (name-3 of X)
   (name-4 of X)
   (name-5 of X))
CLIPS>      
(deffunction in-order (?n1 ?n2)
   (< (str-compare ?n1 ?n2) 0))
CLIPS>    
(defrule r1
   (object (name ?name1&[name-1] | [name-2] | [name-3] | [name-4]))
   (object (name ?name2&[name-1] | [name-2] | [name-3] | [name-4]))
   (test (in-order ?name1 ?name2))
   =>)
CLIPS>    
(defrule r2
   (exists
      (object (name ?name1&[name-1] | [name-2] | [name-3] | [name-4]))
      (object (name ?name2&[name-1] | [name-2] | [name-3] | [name-4])) 
      (test (in-order ?name1 ?name2)))
   =>)
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      r1: [name-1],[name-4]
0      r1: [name-3],[name-4]
0      r1: [name-1],[name-3]
0      r2: *
For a total of 4 activations.
CLIPS>
```